# SQLite3 to Postgres Database Migration Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I did the following:

1. Created `sample_app` as given in the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/)
   Chapter 3 and used the SQLite3 database; works as expected.
2. Installed Postgres.app.
3. Created the following database in Postgres: `sample_app_development`.
4. Created the Postgres user: myapp with password.
5. Issued the following command:

   `sqlite3 development.sqlite3 .dump | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U myapp -W sample_app_development`

With these results; password for user myapp:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PRAGMA"

LINE 1: PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
    ^

BEGIN

COMMIT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Basically - a dump from a DBMS is not supposed to work to another DBMS. Sometimes, it might work, but that's an exception.

Generally, DBMSs have standard SQL for manipulating data, but they don't share the same language for creating and organizing data.

There is no PRAGMA instruction in PostgreSQL. Check the following link:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/plpgsql-porting.html#CO.PLPGSQL-PORTING-PRAGMA